# How do I call a JS callbacks from C++ with node-addon-api?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node-addon-api

I need a way to invoke JS callbacks from a C library that uses contexts.

Here's an example:

```js
const ctx1 = mylib_init();
mylib_set_event_callback(ctx1, () => {
  console.log("EVENT");
});
```

```cpp
Napi::FunctionReference cb;
bool done = false; // Used to prevent crash on multithreading.
// TSFN would obviously be used; this is just to shorten it.

extern "C" void onEvent(mylib_t* handle, void* userdata) {
  if (cb != nullptr && !done) {
    done = true;
    cb.Call({});
  }
}

Napi::Value MyWrapper::SetEventCallback(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info) {
  Napi::Env env = info.Env();
  Napi::Object global = env.Global();

  // info[0] = mylib_t* previously converted to a BigInt.
  // info[1] = JS callback
  mylib_t* handle = convertJSBigIntToHandle(info[0]);

  r_cb = Napi::Persistent(info[1].As<Napi::Function>());
  const auto ret = mylib_set_callback(handle, onEvent, nullptr);
  return env.Null();
}
```

This works (the JS callback is run), but the problem is that the callback is global.
If I have `ctx2` and call `mylib_set_event_callback` again, it will overwrite the callback from `ctx1`.

How can I convert this so that callbacks for `ctx1` and `ctx2` will both be called?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is global because it is in a global variable.

You should place the `Napi::FunctionReference` in the `mylib_t` structure.

If you cannot modify that structure, I see that you can pass a a context pointer in `userdata` - you are passing `nullptr`. Create dynamically a `Napi::FunctionReference` with `new` and pass this pointer so that you can have it in `onEvent`.

You should also properly the reference when the structure is destroyed or the function is replaced.